# Unable to translate text using translate(Microsoft Provider)

Tags: translate, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

I have been using the translate package from https://pypi.org/project/translate/ to do some text translations. The provider used is microsoft. 
When used its unable to translate some simple text which was possible using google trans.

```
from translate import Translator
translate = Translator(provider='microsoft', to_lang='en', secret_access_key='xxxx')

translate.translate('作成者')
```

> Out[20]: '作成者'

Can someone help me with the issue?

**Expected result :**

```
google_translator.translate('作成者',dest='en').text
```

> Out[22]: 'Author'

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [repository](https://github.com/terryyin/translate-python) of the package you are using and it looks like it has been long since it was last updated.

It uses the [Base URL](https://github.com/terryyin/translate-python/blob/20b8e892a97ab02c0708269c236ad1f12083a2d8/translate/providers/microsoft.py#L58) of [Translator Text API v2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v2-0-reference#get-translate) which was deprecated at the beginning of 2018:

```
https://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/Translate
```

Which is different from the one that the new [Translator Text API v3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/reference/v3-0-reference#base-urls) uses:

```
api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com
```

In order to get going, I suggest you check the [Python, REST quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-python-translate) in the documentation that shows you how to translate a text string using Python and the Translator Text REST API, or if you'd like you can check all the [code](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/Text-Translation-API-V3-Python) at once!